How to get an ordered list of vertices defining an island/region in a heightmap array
So I'm trying to create my own navmesh right now for fun. I've been able to construct a heightmap where each cell stores whether it's walkable(blue) or unwalkable(red).
Heightmap Visualization
What I need to do now is actually generate the boundaries of the blue regions as an ordered list of vertices so I can use them in a Douglas-Peucker algorithm and a CDT. Right now I know which cell belongs to region and am able to get all the cells in that region that are on some sort of boundary whether inner or outer.
First off how would I able to be separate these boundary cells into ones that create holes in the region and the cells that define the overall shape(concave hull) of the region?
Then how would I take that information and convert it into an ordered list of vertices? I want to be able to draw along the edges of the cells instead of from the center as well to support places where the width of a walkable region is just 1.?
Topview of Heightmap
This is the topview of the same geometry. I've been looking into image segmentation techniques to accomplish this as it seems applicable in this case but I just can't get anything working past determing which region a cell belongs too and if a cell is a on a boundary or not.
I've seen this post:
Finding Edges and Vertices Within Heightmap Array
but it doesn't mention anything about how to draw along the edges of cells and deal with holes right now which is my biggest struggle.
Also maybe it's a misnomer to describe what is being displayed as a heightmap anymore because it has been simplified into a binary value of 0 or 1 after doing all the heightmap calculations/filtering but this is new territory so yea.

Ok I solved the least important part of this lol. It's trivially easy to get the vertices along the cell edges instead of the center. Because I know which direction has valid neighbors or not I can just keep a byte that basically keeps track of the directions that have a non connecting cell. I think this might also allow me to walk a contour as well. Though I'll still have the final problem of not knowing whether a list of vertices define a hole or the actual hull of the region.

To find if it's a hole or a hull you can use Green's theorem. Basically walk around the contour and integrate - in one direction (e.g. holes) the integral will be negative. The wikipedia page on Green's theorem is a bit of a trainwreck but integrating is simple, you just choose an axis (e.g. the x axis) and for each line segment calculate the area of the trapezoid formed by the line segment and its projection onto the axis. Should be negative if the segment goes from higher to lower x. Add them up all the way around to get the integral (the area of the hull or negative area of the hole).

Oh sick, that's really cool. Thank you!

Starting with a bit mask image of walkable pixels, this task is pretty straightforward:

Scan all the pixels in the image from top to bottom (major) and left to right. Consider the top edge of the pixel and the pixel above.

When you encounter a boundary (pixel is different from the one above) that hasn't been traced already, trace the outline of the connected shape using length-1 segments.
Always trace in a clockwise direction around the filled region. When you start tracing at a top boundary, it's an object. Orient to the right. When you start tracing at a bottom boundary, it's a hole. Orient to the left.

When you start tracing a hole, look up from the bottom boundary you started at to find the hole or object boundary above it. This will already have been traced, and is part of the same object.  Group paths for the same object together.


To "trace around a boundary", imagine standing on the walkable pixel with your  left hand on the boundary, and then:

If the pixel in front of you is not walkable, then turn right.  Your hand moves to the boundary that was in front;
Otherwise if the pixel forward and then left is walkable, then move into that pixel and turn left.  Your hand is now on the boundary with the same pixel as before, but has moved counter-clockwise to a different side;
Otherwise just move forward.

Do this until you come around to the same position and direction that you started at.
A reasonably efficient implementation of all this uses a matrix of integers that keeps track of which object, if any, every horizontal boundary belongs to.
Implementation in python:
walkableMask = [
    "                    ",
    "    ###             ",
    "  ###     #####     ",
    "       ######       ",
    "      ###   ###     ",
    "        ######      ",
    "     ######         ",
    "    ###   ####      ",
]

# Test to see if a pixel is walkable
def isWalkable(mask, x, y):
    if x < 0 or y < 0 or y >= len(mask) or x >= len(mask[y]):
        return False
    return mask[y][x] == "#"

# Trace a boundary and return a list of coordinates on the boundary
def traceBoundary(
    mask,
    trackmatrix, # trackMatrix[y][x] is object owning top boundary of (x,y)
    x,y, # starting position inside walkable object
    dir, # starting direction - number of left turns from right-facing
    objectid # object id of the boundary
):
    # boundary start - position, by direction
    BSX = [0,0,1,1]
    BSY = [0,1,1,0]
    # coordinate changes for directions
    DX = [1,0,-1,0]
    DY = [0,-1,0,1]
    # initial boundary point
    startx = x + BSX[dir]
    starty = y + BSY[dir]
    # start result list
    ret=[(startx,starty)]
    while True:
        dx = DX[dir]
        dy = DY[dir]
        # mark boundary owner
        if dir == 0:
            trackmatrix[y][x] = objectid
        elif dir == 2 and y+1 < len(trackmatrix):
            trackmatrix[y+1][x] = objectid
        # check pixel in front
        if (isWalkable(mask, x+dx, y+dy)):
            # check forward and left
            if (isWalkable(mask, x+dx+dy, y+dy-dx)):
                # boundary turns left
                x = x+dx+dy
                y = y+dy-dx
                dir = (dir+1) % 4
            else:
                # move forward
                x += dx
                y += dy
        else:
            # boundary turns right
            dir = (dir+3) % 4
        # start point of new boundary segment
        bx = x + BSX[dir]
        by = y + BSY[dir]
        if bx == startx and by == starty:
            break
        ret.append((bx,by))
    return ret

# get a list of objects in the mask
# each object is a list of paths
# each path is a list of coordinates
def getObjects(mask):
    hei = len(mask)
    wid = len(mask[0]) 
    # track matrix - object id for boundary above each pixel.  -1 for no object
    # add an extra row for bottom-most boundaries
    trackmatrix = [[-1]*wid for y in range(hei+1)]
    objects = []
    # iterate over all pixels
    for y in range(hei+1):
        for x in range(wid):
            # check boundary above x,y
            if trackmatrix[y][x] >= 0:
                continue
            wup = isWalkable(mask, x, y-1)
            wdown = isWalkable(mask, x, y)
            if wdown and not wup:
                # start of object
                objectid = len(objects)
                path = traceBoundary(mask, trackmatrix, x, y, 0, objectid)
                objects.append([path])
            elif wup and not wdown:
                # hole in object
                ty = y-1
                while trackmatrix[ty][x] < 0:
                    ty -= 1
                    if ty < 0:
                        raise "Impossible error"
                objectid = trackmatrix[ty][x]
                path = traceBoundary(mask, trackmatrix, x, y-1, 2, objectid)
                objects[objectid].append(path)
    return objects


# render an object list in ASCII
def renderObjects(objects):
    output = []
    def setOutput(x,y,c):
        while len(output) <= y:
            output.append([])
        while len(output[y]) <= x:
            output[y].append(" ")
        output[y][x] = c

    for obji in range(len(objects)):
        obj = objects[obji]
        objchar = str(obji % 10)
        for path in obj:
            for x,y in path:
                setOutput(x*3,y*2,objchar)
            for pathi in range(len(path)):
                x1,y1 = path[pathi]
                x2,y2 = path[(pathi+1)%len(path)]
                if y1 == y2:
                    setOutput(min(x1,x2)*3+1,y1*2,"-")
                    setOutput(min(x1,x2)*3+2,y1*2,"-")
                if x1 == x2:
                    setOutput(x1*3,min(y1,y2)*2+1,"|")
    for s in output:
        print("".join(s))


objects = getObjects(walkableMask)
renderObjects(objects)

Output:

            0--0--0--0
            |        |
      0--0--0  0--0--0        1--1--1--1--1--1
      |        |              |              |
      0--0--0--0     1--1--1--1        1--1--1
                     |                 |
                  1--1     1--1--1--1  1--1--1
                  |        |        |        |
                  1--1--1  1--1--1--1     1--1
                        |                 |
               1--1--1--1        1--1--1--1
               |                 |
            1--1     1--1--1--1  1--1--1--1
            |        |        |           |
            1--1--1--1        1--1--1--1--1

